# How to enable in-word breaking without a hyphen?

Tags: line-breaking

Consider the following ridiculous example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\end{document}
```

This produces an overfull hbox. I want to allow the word to break at any point, without a hyphen.

Of course, I can work around like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}a

\end{document}
```

But this is far too ugly.

(I want to enable this only for a particular word, because I don't want my whole document to break.)

Comment: By "without a hyphen", do you mean there should not be a hyphen even if the word is broken?

Comment: @schtandard Yes. The word is not really a "word" in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `seqsplit` package does it quite nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit} 

\begin{document}

\noindent \seqsplit{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! A dedicated package is the best option!

Answer (score 4):

xurl package will break everywhere without inserting hyphen

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xurl}
\DeclareUrlCommand\longword{\urlstyle{rm}}


\begin{document}

\longword{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, then the whole word is in monospace font. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: @L.F. see edited

Comment: (+1) Good to know! I guess I will give a chance for other answers.

Comment: With this approach, it's important to specify the option `obeyspaces`.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1{\zzz#1\relax}
\def\zzz#1{\ifx\relax #1\else #1\penalty0 \expandafter\zzz\fi}

\begin{document}

\zz{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you need non-asciii letters you need to work a bit harder.

Comment: It is always useful to see what actually happens under the hood!